# addProximityAlert does not fire the intent

Tags: android, gps, locationmanager

I tried to implement the addProximityAlert method, it works fine on my phone but did not fire the intent on another device. 
Here are my codes
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXRdE.jpg)

```
private void addProximityAlert(double lati, double longti, int stationId) {
    Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.xb.PROXIMITY_ALERT");
    intent.setAction("com.example.xb.PROXIMITY_ALERT");
    //sendBroadcast(intent);
    intent.putExtra("stationId", stationId);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this,
            stationId, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    lm.addProximityAlert(lati, longti, 100, -1, pi);
}
```

it worked fine on my phone(android 5.1),BroadcastReceiver.onReceive() would be called as except when i enter the area given by the location. But when i am debugging the application on another device(android 4.2), the intent would not be fired by addProximityAlert() even if i entered the area given by the location.Can somebody help me?  thanks a lot